# How to call IFormFile parameter and FromForm parameter together for a unit/integration test in ASP.NET Core webapi?

Tags: .net-core, c#-4.0

Controller action method like below

```
    [HttpPost("InternalDocUpload")]
    [ApiVersion("1")]
    public ActionResult Upload([FromForm] Doc item, IFormFile file)
   {
   }
```

Test case written like below

public async Task FileUpload()

```
    {
        //Arrange
        //Setup mock file using a memory stream
        var content = "Hello World from a Fake File";
        var fileName = "test" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n").Substring(0, 4)+".pdf";
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        //create FormFile with desired data
        IFormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, "id_from_form", fileName);

        //formData            
        var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent() {
            { new StringContent("123"), "DetailNo" },
            { new StringContent(fileName), "FileNameWithExt" },
            { new StringContent("admin"), "User" },
        };

        // Act           
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("/api/v1/TestUpload/Upload",
                    ContentHelper.GetStringContent(formData));
    }
```

from  _client.PostAsync how to call two parameters. Please help